# compare 2 xmls with different tags in java

Tags: java, xml, xmlunit

I wanted to compare 2 XMLs, which have the same data but the tag names are different. I need to compare two (input and output) and show the result using JAVA.

eg.

XML 1

```
<hometown>newyork</hometown>
...
```

XML 2

```
<city>newyork</city>
```

I need to verify that the `hometown` tag value from XML 1 is same as the `city` tag value from XML 2.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Not enough information.  Are the document structures identical, differing only in the tag names? What constitutes "equal" for two nodes? Do you have to cope with insertions and deletions?  The general case of comparing two arbitrary hierarchies is non-trivial, and adequately describing a solution is beyond SO (it would require a tutorial-length answer).  If you have some simplifying assumptions it could be a relatively easy problem, but with the given information it's hard to tell.

Comment: Thanks Jim for the replay.

The structure is not identical. It is something like, using the info available in xml1, there are more than 1 xmls are created with different tag names (with different structures).

I just have to test that the system which is doing that (creating new xmls) is working fine, obviously by comparing the values.

hope this clears few things.

thanks

Comment: @eurostar07 are there more tags with the same names in your documents? What's the structure of your files? Please update your question with such information. It really is too vague to answer properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I took an approach like, I created a mapping document which says which Tag from input is mapped to which tag in output. Then I parse both input and output XMLs and the converted them into HashMaps (key value pair). Now when I want to compare the value from input XML, I loop through list of inputTags and search the counterpart of the tag from mapping sheet and once I have values for both input and output tag, I compare it and publish the results

Answer (score 1):

The question is pretty broad. Given the information provided, I think it would be a good idea to use an in-memory representation of the document trees like DOM or JDOM. Streaming parsers like StAX or SAX will be much harder to use when comparing documents with different structures. If both formats are similarly expressive, another way to do it would be to use XML transform to turn one document into the format of the other. Then canonicalize both and do a straight textual difference after that.